# How can I format a string to remove leading zeros?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a number that I want to put in a string.

```
x = 0.13
```

How can I format my string so that the leading zero does not appear?

```
print('This is my formatted number: {formating}'.format(x))
>> This is my formatted number: .13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `strip` method:

```
x = 0.13
res = str(x).strip('0')
print('This is my formatted number: {}'.format(res))
```

Comment: Suppose x was a float and I wanted to truncate it to two decimal places but remove the leading zero. Is there an easy way to do that in python 3?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `round` function: ```res = str(round(x, 2)).strip('0')```